# How to prevent showing multiple DialogFragments in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have some custom DialogFragments in my Android application. I would prevent the user from opening multiple dialogs, and I would also avoid disabling the button which shows the dialog once it's pressed or using a variable or it.

So I was trying to make an extension for the fragment which checks for shown fragments via their tags like this:

```
fun Fragment.isFragmentVisible(tag: String): Boolean {
    val fragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)
    if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

And before showing the dialog to check it like this:

```
    binding.destination.editText?.setOnClickListener {
        if (!isFragmentVisible(ShopsDialog.TAG)) {
            ShopsDialog.newInstance(this, "Destinazione") { bundle ->
                val shopId = bundle.getString("shopId")
                viewModel.setDestination(shopId)
            }
        }
    }
```

While the newInstance is:

```
   fun newInstance(fragment: Fragment, title: String, bundle: (Bundle) -> Unit) = ShopsDialog().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putString(ARG_TITLE, title)
        }

        fragment.setFragmentResultListener(KEY_CALLBACK_BUNDLE) { requestKey: String, bundle: Bundle ->
            if (requestKey == KEY_CALLBACK_BUNDLE) {
                bundle(bundle)
            }
        }
        show(fragment.childFragmentManager, TAG)
    }
```

But this seems not to work, I've tried even to use `requireActivity().supportFragmentManager` instead `childFragmentManager` but still nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before showing bottomsheetdialogfragment , i think you can check it like this

```
if(childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ShopsDialog::class.java.simpleName) == null){
   // show your bottom sheet dialog fragment
  
}
```

If you are going to show bottomSheetDialogFragment in Fragment then use `childFragmentManager` and if it is activity then use `supportFragmentManager`

Comment: Oh the main issue was with `fragment.isVisible` by removing it I resolved the issue